# Skip authentication for specific collection action in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to skip the authentication for a custom ActiveAdmin collection action.

in active_admin initializer I have the following configuration:

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_user!
config.current_user_method = :current_user
```

Authentication works fine, but when you try to skip authentication for a specific action the following error is displayed.

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :check
```

> Before process_action callback :authenticate_user! has not been
>   defined

Comment: Can you try adding `raise: false` to your `skip_before_action`? It looks like a Rails issue: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4207#issuecomment-234587685

Comment: @MrShemek yes I tried, but the error continues, it just is not displayed

Comment: Okay, another solution: `before_action :authenticate_user!, except: :check`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this in your Base/Application controller ...

```
class ActiveAdmin::BaseController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, except: :check
end
```